# How To Increase Maximum Iteration Limit For e1071 package In R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I am using e1071 package in R to train my SVM classification model using radial kernel.
I have a dataset of around 4,000,000 rows and 19 columns .
Whenever i try to train the model i get a warning "Maximum Number Of Iteration Reached". I did a bit of research and found that my model did not converge but has reached the maximum number of iteration limit as set in the code of e1071 library.
I want to increase the interation limit so that i can converge the model.
Please help where to make changes in the package source code to increase the limit.

Comment: Since the data set is hefty I recommend using [LiquidSVM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/liquidSVM/index.html) its much faster then e1071. Additionally you can attempt [kernlab](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html).

Comment: decreset tolerance